# Bash - Take input from user and send a command having that input in tmux

Tags: bash, tmux, read

I am running several dedicated servers on different tmux sessions.
I have to change ports and have to write a command in all the tmux sessions.
The command is: `config['Port'] = 12345`, 12345 being the port.
I tried to write a script which would take inputs from me and type the whole code with the code I input into all the different tmux sessions, but it doesn't work. The name of the session is `43210`.

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p '43210: ' avar
tmux attach-session -t 43210 "config['Port'] = ${avar}"
```

But it never works and shows:

```
usage: attach-session [-dr] [-t target-session]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use double-quotes to expand variables in `bash` shell. What you done is passed `avar` as a literal string to `tmux attach-session` even though you have a value stored in the variable. Since single-quotes do not expand shell variables, you need prefix a `$` before the variable name and double-quote it.

Change your script to something like,

```
read -p '43210: ' avar
tmux attach-session -t 43210 "config['Port'] = ${avar}"
```